# ocLazyLoad + UI Router navigating back to child view after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, angular-ui-router

I'm using ocLazyLoad with AngularJS and AngularJS UI Router to load AngualarJS modules on demand. I have a Posts view/state and Post view/state in different modules and I can simply navigate between them.

The only issue is that when I'm on **/posts/1** and manually refresh the page, it goes back to **/**. I understand that it makes perfect sense because app.js is the only file that gets loaded after page refresh but what I don't understand is how to make it lazy load the same **/posts/1** view again after refreshing the page. I tried using **$urlRouterProvider.when** in app.js but had no luck.

I have created a plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/lPb2qCGF9KLL16jVoLQo?p=info

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad'])
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.state = $state;
        $rootScope.stateParams = $stateParams;
    }
])
.config([
    '$ocLazyLoadProvider',
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',

    function ($ocLazyLoadProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    header: {
                      template:
                      '<nav class="navbar navbar-default">' +
                        '<div class="container-fluid">' +
                          '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' +
                            '<li><a ui-sref="app">Home</a></li>' +
                            '<li><a ui-sref="app.posts">Posts</a></li>' +
                          '</ul>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</nav>'
                    },
                    content: {
                        template: '<h3>Home view</h3>'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.posts', {
                url: 'posts',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'posts.html',
                        controller: 'PostsController',
                        resolve: {
                            load: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                    serie: true,
                                    files: [
                                        'posts.js',
                                        'posts-controller.js'
                                    ]
                                });
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
]);
```

**posts.js**

```
angular.module('app.posts', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad'])
.config([
    '$ocLazyLoadProvider',
    '$stateProvider',

    function ($ocLazyLoadProvider, $stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('app.posts.post', {
                url: '/:id',
                views: {
                    post: {
                        templateUrl: 'post.html',
                        controller: 'PostController',
                        resolve: {
                            post: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                    serie: true,
                                    files: [
                                        'post.js',
                                        'post-controller.js'
                                    ]
                                });
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
]);
```

**post.js**

```
angular.module('app.posts.post', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading ui-router states with ocLazyLoad and ui-router-extras futureStates

http://bardo.io/2014/08/26/oclazyload-future-states/